# Memory issue with block, when it is transferred from swift to objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, refactoring, objective-c-blocks

maybe someone will have thoughts on solving an interesting problem. There is an obj-c method, which I rewrite to Swift:
https://pp.userapi.com/c846018/v846018818/1a0713/zsa8UZFcnfY.jpg

```
 + (instancetype)postUdpateTechnicianPhotoRequest:(UIImage*)image;
 {   

  ....

  SCRequest* requset =
  [IFTRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl
                httpMethod:HTTPMethodPOST
                parameters:nil
                   headers:@{ @"Content-Type" : [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] }];

  [requset.updateRequestBlocksArray addObject:^(SCRequest *req) {

    [req setDataToHTTPBody:body];
  }];

  requset.hudTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Uploading photo...", @"");
  requset.failureBlock = [requset defaultFailure];

  return requset;
  }
```

Got this Swift method, which is most likely the problem:

```
 let request = IFTRequest(url: requestUrl, httpMethod: .POST, parameters: nil, headers: ["Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"])
    let updateBlock: UpdateRequestBlock = {
        $0?.setDataToHTTPBody(body)
    }

    request?.updateRequestBlocksArray.add(updateBlock)
```

The logic is simple, we add a block with data to the array and then call this block in the obj-c class. The block is typedef:

```
typedef void (^UpdateRequestBlock) (SCRequest* request);
```

The problem is that according to the result this block is out of memory, NULL as a whole.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you stick to either Swift or Objective-C within the method. It's hard to tell what is going on, in your little snippet where the updateBlock is NULL. Show the complete method and if you are using instance variables, say what type they are and if it is a Swift or an Objective-C type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with NSMutableArray between Swift and ObjC. Variables are captured differently, and later problems with objects inside the array can arise. The problem was solved by replacing NSMutableArray with NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Objective-C blocks and Swift functions are different types of things. If Swift sees that you are passing a Swift closure to an Objective-C function parameter that takes an Objective-C block type, it will convert the Swift closure to an Objective-C block, so it will work. But here you are passing it to the method `-addObject:` of `NSMutableArray`, which takes a parameter of type `id`, which is a generic (not block-specific) Objective-C object type. In this case it doesn't need to do the conversion into an Objective-C block because Swift closures can be passed into Objective-C and used as Objective-C objects directly. But this Objective-C object that it can be used in Objective-C as is not an Objective-C block, and you cannot use in Objective-C like a block. It's just an opaque object that wraps a Swift value.

I believe if you want to force it to convert into an Objective-C block when you pass it to `-addObject:`, you can do something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
request?.updateRequestBlocksArray.addObject(myBlock as @convention(block) SCRequest -> Void)
```